# NDepend - Folder name hints

Tags: ndepend

I use NDepend.Console.exe (NDepend version 2022.1.4) to create **.ndpro**j from command line - /cp flag.

The build script changes my build path to **FinalDLLs\bin\x64(or 86)/Release** instead of **\bin\x64(or x86)\Release**.
I tried using the folder name hints but no luck. I always get an errors "*Cannot get assembly file path ....*"
What is the correct syntax for folder name hints? I tried all combinations with FinalDLLs but they are always ignored.

Please, don't ask me why I want to use such path prefix. It must be FinalDLLs!

Comment: How do you provide folder name hint to a project created through NDepend.Console.exe /cp ?  here are both features links  https://www.ndepend.com/docs/ndepend-console#create-project    https://www.ndepend.com/docs/ndepend-assemblies-resolving#resolving-assemblies-in-root-folder

Comment: I actually used NDepend.Console.exe to create the project file and add the filters, and later use a PowerShell script to change the XML node (RootDirResolvingInfo[@Hints]), but that's not important at this point. I also tried to set the hints from VisualNdepend but no luck. How exactly does NDepend analyze hints?

Comment: see all details about hints here, are you using separator | and wildcard * ? https://www.ndepend.com/docs/ndepend-assemblies-resolving#resolving-assemblies-in-root-folder

Comment: I just compare with OrchardCore. It works as expected, find artefacts is any folder. Maybe my project has a wrong structure. I have to inspect it.

Comment: I found the culprit. My solution have different project and AssembliesName. If I use "Add VS Solution or Project" assemblies was not found. But if I use "Add Assemblies from VS Solution" most of them is added and it is fine. 
Powershell script is to slow, so I want to implement "Add Assemblies from VS Solution" using NDepend API, but I only found **GetAssembliesFromVisualStudioSolutionOrProject** and it seems it is for "Add VS Solution or Project". 


Is there API method for  **"Add Assemblies from VS Solution"**?

Comment: You need a two steps approach here with NDepend.API, first retrieve the assemblies with **GetAssembliesFromVisualStudioSolutionOrProject ** and then **project.CodeToAnalyze.SetApplicationAssemblies** as illustrated by the code here: https://www.ndepend.com/docs/ndepend-api-quickstart#Getting-Started